# Auto connect VPN in Cisco AnyConnect on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, login

I would like to connect automatically after I logon in my computer. For that I need some form to pass my user and password to Cisco Anyconnect.

I tried to use the `-s` option in `/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn` but not matter what I do, I tried a zillion different ways, the VPN doesn't take into consideration my username and password, no matter where I put it.

I saw that there is an option in my profile that forbidden scripting: EnableScripting, at `/opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile/AnyConnectProfile.xml`.
Then I ask myself if this holds and if yes, would be possible to find an alternative path without the need of involving the network administrators.

Any help?

Comment: Most companies using Cisco VPN will have a profile that enables the tunnel before your user account logs in. That’s preferable to them than storing your password and scripting it. Are you sure they won’t help you bring up the VPN tunnel from a pre-shared key instead of your personal credentials?

Comment: Not, they cannot change how things connect here. The HD is also encrypted.

Comment: Wouldn’t this go against company policy? Companies protect data behind VPN’s - if your computer auto logged in then anyone that gets into your computer will be able to connect to private company data (as opposed to needing to log in).

Answer (score 0):

We have AnyConnect support in [VPN Tracker 365 Pro](https://www.vpntracker.com) our multi-protocol VPN client for the Mac. We added full support for password storing, InfiniConnect automatic reconnecting etc.

There's a free demo - feel free to hit me up with any questions!

Disclaimer: I work on the team building VPN Tracker :)

Comment: Does your client somehow bypass or disable a work vpn from Cisco where split tunneling is disabled? Thank you for disclosing your relationship with the product and suggesting how it might solve the problem at hand.

Comment: Yes: we have a feature called Traffic Control where you can set custom routing rules up, in addition to those pushed by the VPN gateway. 
You can choose which traffic to exclude from the tunnel (e.g. your local network), or choose to only send certain routes over the VPN (e.g. just your company networks), effectively creating a split tunnel setup.